When printing from electron-pos-printer, the content prints but prints a blank first page
I am using electron-pos-printer v1.3.6 in my electron app to print an image, The image prints out but I get 2 pages, the first is an empty label and the second is the image that should be printed.
This is my PosPrintOptions timeoutPerLine = 5000
const options: PosPrintOptions = {
    boolean: undefined,
    copies: 1,
    landscape: false,
    margin: '0 0 0 0',
    preview: false,
    printBackground: false,
    printerName: settings.get('printer') as string,
    silent: false,
    timeOutPerLine: DEFAULT_PRINTER_TIMEOUT,
};

My PosPrintData is
const printData: PosPrintData[] = [
    {
        path: outputFilePath,
        position: 'center',
        type: 'image',
    },
];

I am printing to a small label printer with labels w50mm x h30mm
I have tried adjusting the margin which does push the label around but still on the second page.
If I set preview: true then it shows the label as expected with no space about it.
